# Determing Sample Size need with Binomial Distribution

Tags: statistics, binomial-theorem, descriptive-statistics

[image: Formula]

Trying to learn how to use this equation.

The author of the paper list example numbers and the answer. Can someone show me a few steps into the problem. I'm getting $r=0$, $r=1$, but can't seem to make it to $r=15$

$q=\frac{1}{64}$, $r=15$, $p=0.95$
Author gives the answer at $n=1397$.

It's a problem on how to find the minimum number of samples needed.

Appreciate any tips, links, etc.

Comment: In accordance with [this Binomial Distribution article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)},~$ shouldn't the exponent applied to $(1-q)$ be $(n-i)$, rather than $(n-1)$.  Am I misunderstanding the intent of the mathematical expression?

Comment: Excluding the (currently unresolved) issue re my previous comment, it seems as if the author is trying to compute how large $n$ has to be so that the probability of *at least* $15$ successful trials out of $n$ total trials equals $p$.  Here, as I interpret the question, the probability that a specific trial is successful is $(1/64).$  If I was attacking this problem, I would write a computer program in Java, C,  Python, or a similar language.  The program would compute $p$ for $n = (1396), n = (1397),~$ and $~n = (1398)$.  Then, I would examine the results and ask myself what they mean.

Comment: Following @user2661923's method in R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, code `n = 1396:1397; 1 - pbinom(14, n, 1/64)` returns $0.9497449, 0.9500721.$ So the Author's answer is correct. // You should be able to use normal approximation to find that something in the high1390s is correct, and then use an exact binomial computation to get the exact $n.$ // The normal approximation is manageable without a computer; I'd want to use a computer (or programable calculator) for the exact binomial computation. Usually, one can't depend on more than 2-place accuracy for normal aprx to binomial.

Comment: you're correct, it should state (n-i)